# How to open a pop up on click of FB login/register..?

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

I want to open a pop-up with URL say http://google.com on click of FB api..

Is it possible...

here is my piece of code and I want to open my own pop-up along with FB login.

I tried this below code. But pop-up getting blocked in IE.

Please help.

```
function fac(){
openPopup();// my function which opens pop up
FB.login(function(response) {                                       
   if (response.authResponse) {                          
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {        
       document.getElementById('fbEmail').value=response.email;
       document.getElementById('fbId').value=response.id;
       document.getElementById('fbFirstname').value=response.first_name;
       document.getElementById('fbLastname').value=response.last_name;
       document.getElementById('fbGender').value=response.gender;
       document.getElementById('birthday').value=response.birthday;        
         //openPopUp();
        loginRegisterFB();
     });
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});

window.open('http://google.com', 'applyurljob', 'height=550, width=800,toolbar=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,left=200, top=250');
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Facebook question. Your popup is being blocked by a popup blocker. That's what popup blockers do. There is no way around this unless the user clicks on a link to open it, or you time JS with a user click really well (I think that is how dodgy sites do it).

Maybe you should think of another way to acheive what you want to acheive.

Comment: HI Adam ... Thanks for your reply... To be simple.... I want to open two pop-ups on single click.. Is thhis possible.... else let me know if it is possilbe to open a pop-up on load ( with out getting blocked by pop-up blocker of any browsers)..

Please help..

Comment: Not possible due to security restrictions. I would advise you to rethink your approach. Popups are annoying and don't follow any well designed UI interace or flow. People like taking things 1 step at a time. Keep it that way.